# FATAL EXCEPTION: (sounds terrible) unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, android-studio, runtime-error

My app won't even run and I'm wondering what is wrong with my code that is causing this error to happen? I am trying to populate a ListView with an array but for some reason the app will not even run.

FirstFragment.java

```
    package layout;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import com.lucasapps.fakeproject.R;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public FirstFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    public ArrayAdapter<String> mNewsTextAdapter;
    public ArrayAdapter<Integer> mNewsImageAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first,container,false);
        ArrayList<String> rightArray = new ArrayList<>();
        rightArray.add("Trump Vs. Clinton");
        rightArray.add("Twins Sign Clayton Kershaw");
        rightArray.add("German Officials Identify Suspect");
        rightArray.add("Silly Party Candidate John Johnson Seeks Debates");

        ArrayList<Integer> leftArray = new ArrayList<>();
        leftArray.add(R.drawable.picture_trumpvsclinton);
        leftArray.add(R.drawable.picture_claytonkershaw);
        leftArray.add(R.drawable.picture_germany);
        leftArray.add(R.drawable.picture_johnjohnson);

        mNewsTextAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.list_item_first,R.id.listView_text_news,rightArray);
        //ListView leftListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView_text_newsImages);
        ListView rightListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView_text_news);
        //leftListView.setAdapter(mNewsImageAdapter);
        rightListView.setAdapter(mNewsTextAdapter);

        //ListView.setOnItemClickListeners
    //        leftListView.setOnItemClickListener(new       AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    //            @Override
    //            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int                 position, long id) {
    //
    //            }
    //        });
        rightListView.setOnItemClickListener(new     AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            }
        });

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.lucasapps.fakeproject;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.MenuItem;

    import layout.FirstFragment;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if(savedInstanceState==null){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new FirstFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        int id = item.getItemId();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Errors

```
07-23 23:29:20.192 1162-1162/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
07-23 23:29:20.192 1162-1162/? I/art: VMHOOK: rlim_cur : 0 pid:1162
07-23 23:29:20.242 1162-1174/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
07-23 23:29:20.383 1162-1162/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.lucasapps.fakeproject, PID: 1162
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lucasapps.fakeproject/com.lucasapps.fakeproject.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.lucasapps.fakeproject.MainActivity@e97057f must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.lucasapps.fakeproject.MainActivity@e97057f must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
     at layout.FirstFragment.onAttach(FirstFragment.java:100)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1019)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:330)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:547)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1288)
     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5974)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2374)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823) 
07-23 23:29:24.167 1162-1162/com.lucasapps.fakeproject D/Process: killProcess, pid=1162
07-23 23:29:24.167 1162-1162/com.lucasapps.fakeproject D/Process: com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException:138 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:693 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:690
```

Comment: add crash reports.

Comment: Look at the stack trace in logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MainActivity` must implement `OnFragmentInteractionListener` because you are casting context received in `onAttach` to `OnFragmentInteractionListener` (which is `context` of `MainActivity`)

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
```

So try like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FirstFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```